# Can attachments be transferred to other corda nodes without being double spend?

Tags: corda

Suppose I have added attachment to one node, can these be transferred to other node, in a secure way that once I send it, I can not send it again. As an ownable state?

Answer (score 1):

Nodes will cache any attachments they see. When they see the same attachment again in subsequent transactions, they will resolve it from local storage instead of redownloading it from their counterparty.

Regarding not sending the same attachment twice, you could write a flow in such a way that a node never sends an attachment twice. However, the logic would be on the sending node, and you couldn't enforce this constraint at the network level.

Ultimately, an attachment is just a piece of data, and it is impossible to prevent one node from sending it to others (either on- or off-platform) if they wish to.

Comment: Thanks joel, it helps to clarify the doubts. Is there a possible roadmap for implementing this part in corda?

Comment: We don't plan to implement this feature. If a party knows a piece of data, there is no way to stop them from sharing it with others.